# jQuery select sort changing displayed option on page refresh. What's happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following jQuery to sort the select elements in a form:

```
$('select.select-sortable').each(function () {
    var options = $(this).children();
    var arr = options.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value }; }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; });
    options.each(function(i, o) {
      o.value = arr[i].v;
      $(o).text(arr[i].t);
    });
});
```

The sorting works, but the displayed value changes on every page refresh. It changes in the order 1st option -> 3rd option -> 2nd option -> 1st option, no matter how many more options are present.

I've added `$(this).children(":first").attr("selected", true);` to the loop, which locks the choice to the first option, but I still don't understand why the dsiplay was changing, and why in that order. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because of browser cache. It stores information about which option (with what value) was selected before pressing reload. If you change option values on the fly, browser will reflect these changes on next reload, but your script will instantly modify the values again. It's playing catch-up with you :)

Btw. you don't have to do constructs like this: `$(this).children(":first").attr("selected", true);` Simple `options[0].selected = true;` placed after `options.each` loop will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mostly because the `selected` attribute of the options is not captured.

```
$('select').each(function () {
    var options = $(this).children();
    var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
      return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value, s: $(o).attr('selected') };
    }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; });
    options.each(function(i, o) {
      o.value = arr[i].v;
      $(o).text(arr[i].t);
      if(arr[i].s!==undefined){
        $(o).attr('selected','selected');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your if statement. When I include it, it stops the sorter from functioning at all.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't work but I've changed the condition to check for undefined value. http://jsbin.com/opuzot/1/edit

Comment: I think the problem is that your function preserves the selection across page loads, but it doesn't set the initial selected value.

To clarify, the value and text fields for the options are slightly different, so that the option with the alphabetically-first text is not the initial default selection, the option with the alphabetically-first value is. This is the value on which the "selected" attribute is applied, so that even though the list is sorted alphabetically by text, it is the first value that is 'selected'.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, it sorts and will select the value the you will pass in .eq()

```
var arr = [],
$select = $("#ddsort"),
$options = $select.children();

$options.each(function(index, obj){
   arr.push($(this).val());
});

Array.sort(arr);
$select.empty();

$.each(arr,function(index, obj){
   $select.append("<option value="+obj+">"+obj+"</option>");   
});

$select.children().eq(2).attr("selected","selected");
```

See working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/tFDNx/3/

I hope it helps.